# New style of hash notation

Tags: ruby

This one works

```
items = Item.where(:item_id.in => items.map(&:id))
```

unlike these two

```
items = Item.where(item_id:.in items.map(&:id))
items = Item.where(item_id.in: items.map(&:id))
```

Is there any way to convert the first expression of  "old style Ruby hash" to the "new style Ruby hash" notation?

Comment: I'm confused by this.  :item_id.in is not a valid symbol literal, and even in rails, with all of it's monkeypatches loaded, there's no in method on symbols.  Are you sure the top one works?

Comment: @tehgeekmeister it is valid syntax tough. `:item_id.in` is a method call `in` to the Symbol object `:item_id`, and [it seems](http://ideone.com/DsdP2E) you can use that as an old-style hash key. Maybe the OP is using some library that defines the `in` method on symbols or something.

Comment: Yes, it's valid syntax, but not a valid symbol literal.  If there's some library adding <code>in</code> to Symbol, then the question should specify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. The `{key: value}` notation for a hash is only available when the key can be written as a symbol literal.